# How to encoding no sound recorded red5 video via ffmpeg

Tags: video, encoding, audio, ffmpeg, red5

HI

We recorded video via red5 server but no sound added ( because there was no sound environment )  . So there is no sound track in output flv file. and there is encoding error when we do encoding that flv ( no sound track ) into other video format via ffmpeg .

error message is 
Could not find codec parameters (Audio: 0x0000, 0 channels, s16)

Pls advice us how to solve the problem .

1. is there any way ffmpeg can encoding no sound track video flv ?
2. is there any way that red5 server can add sound track even there is actually no sound recorded ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

We could better assist you if you had your FFmpeg command line in your question.  Regardless, to answer your second question:

> Is there any way ffmpeg can encoding no sound track video flv?

**Yes, with the `-an` switch!**

This can be found in the **[FFmpeg documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html)**.  Your new command line will look something like this:

```
./ffmpeg -i myred5recording.flv -an myoutput.mp4
```

It is also possible to 'mux in' audio with FFmpeg, but that is non-trivial relative to just using the `-an` switch.  If you want to pursue this angle, the have a look at some other Stack Overflow questions, such as [How can I add audio (mp3) to a flv (just video) with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329333/how-can-i-add-audio-mp3-to-a-flv-just-video-with-ffmpeg)